# php session_start default value?

Tags: php, session

I have a question regarding a session variable.

I have session variable which needs to start at a default variable. Then I need to be able to pass a new one through `$_GET` and keep that updated. So that even if the user reloads the page, it does not go back to the default value. How might I go about doing this? Thanks!

Comment: Just program each step of the algorithm you've described and ask a **specific question** when you'll have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like something along these lines might work:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['my_parm']))
{
  $_SESSION['my_parm'] = 'DEFAULT';
}

if(isset($_GET['my_parm']))
{
  $_SESSION['my_parm']=$my_parm;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working. After I change pages on my pagination, it does not stay at the amount of pages I want to show (my mysql LIMIT) which is the get variable I am trying to pass

Answer (score 2):

With this snippet you'll have session variable assigning once:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['magic'])) {
    $_SESSION['magic'] = isset($_GET['magic']) ? $_GET['magic'] : 1;
}
```

Comment: would I just add:

else
$_SESSION['magic'] = 1;    (or whatever I want my default to be?)

because unfortunately that is breaking it ha

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
session_start();
$_SESSION
```

below is the link for session manual

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Comment: Right, but I need to be able to update it to a $_GET variable, and then keep that even if the page is reloaded, and not go back to the starting default value

Comment: @rick , you can do it as per zerkms answer

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, this would be an outline of your method:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_GET['my_variable'])) {
    $_SESSION['my_variable'] = $_GET['my_variable']; // force new value
}
if (!isset($_SESSION['my_variable'])) {
    $_SESSION['my_variable'] = $default_value; // initialize
}
update_value($_SESSION['my_variable']);
```